Как учить C#, чтобы создавать телеграм ботов?
Заранее хочу сказать что мой вопрос какой-то НАИСТРАННЫЙ, но я сейчас учу C#, одной из цели его обучения я хочу писать телеграм ботов. Что мне нужно учить что бы грамотно писать тг ботов ? Одно я знаю что есть библиотека Telegram.Bot и там используется асинхронность. В общем не могли бы дать какой-то четкий план.

"Бот" - это очень размытое понятие, ибо условный var bot = new SomeBot(); bot.OnNewMessage += ...; bot.Start(...); - это тоже бот, не так-ли? 3 строки кода, которые поймет любой человек. Так что, я бы вам порекомендовал взять более реальную задачу, не такую абстрактную как "бот", а что-то существенное, что-то, что может быть полезно и интересно вам. Имея ее, уже оттачивайте там свои навыки, достигайте поставленных целей. А чтоб не забить и была хоть какая-то ответственность, сделайте проект Open Source и ведите его постепенно для людей. Ну а после, боты для вас будут довольно простой задачей

Если вам всеж нужен список того, что нужно именно для бота, то: 1. API - вы должны понимать как работает тот-же телеграмм бот под капотом, вы должны понимать что такое POST/GET запросы, должны понимать как их отправлять самостоятельно. 2. Как вы верно указали в метках, Асинхронность - без нее достичь нормальной отзывчивости невозможно. 3. Паттерны по типу "Машина состояния" - это один из основных подходов, который позволяет вам не просто делать ping-pong сообщения, а строить сложную логику. 4. Работа с базами - вы должны понимать как работать с данными, как их хранить и забирать. Ну и т.д.

Каков вопрос, таков наистранный ответ:

Базовые типы C#
Классы и методы
Коллекции, циклы
Рекурсия: стек вызовов, переполнение стека
Исключения и их перехват/обработка, трассировка стека
ООП и SOLID
Модификаторы доступа и другие модификаторы в C# (private, public, static, readonly и т.д.)
Шаблон проектирования "итератор" и итераторы в C#
Linq
Шаблон проектирования "конечный автомат" ("машина состояний") - важное
Интерфейсы и абстрактные классы, наследование и полиморфизм в C# (virtual/override)
Сборщик мусора, как работает управление памятью в C#: аллокации, IDisposable
Основы асинхронного программирования с использованием async/await
Многопоточное программирование и пул потоков в C#
Потокобезопасность, потокобезопасные коллекции, примитивы синхронизации, типичные проблемы многопоточного программирования (гонка потоков, дедлоки)
Контекст синхронизации в асинхронном программировании (класс SynchronizationContext)
Библиотека Telegram.Bot
Системы контроля версий (Git)
Работа с сетью, сетевые протоколы, класс HttpClient
Кеширование (Redis, Memcached)
Базы данных (Entity Framework)

Это навскидку, надеюсь ничего критичного не упустил.

Теперь автор вопроса наверняка расхочет писать ботов и переключится на что-то попроще ))

@CrazyElf Мне наоборот понравилось остально по немного начать все это изучать!
